# SSAS Calculated Table without data

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dax

I am developing a SSAS tabular model , and I have one calculated table for the dates (=DimDate).
When I use the model in Power BI or in SSMS, the calculated table has no rows.

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Process the table, if that doesn't work you may need to rebuild it. I've noticed SSAS can be finicky with calculated tables sometimes.

[image]

Comment: This is a suggestion not an definitive answer and should be posted as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Adriani6

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think that the problem could be produced because of DirectQuery mode used in Power BI. But it is suspicious that SSAS-T doesn't have any fast way to create table "alias" instead of calculated tables.

Comment: can confirm a process recalc fixed a similar issue (a new calculated table which errored as 'needs recalculation' to a clean table in Power BI). Note that I couldn't find the option on the table itself, had to process recalc the full database for it to work.